# nginx proxy_cache_key

Tags: testing, nginx

How does this key work?
Can't get it from [here][1]:

```
 syntax:    proxy_cache_key string; default:     proxy_cache_key
 $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri; context:   http, server, location
 Defines a key for caching, for example
 proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
```

e.g. if I set it to $`host$filename`
what does it mean? how can I test if this change was applied in `nginx`?

Notes:

- Don't ask me to show full config, because I don't have it.
- The matter is - I have the `api` interface to a server and want to check if it works.
- cucumber(or whatever) scenario will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you forgot to add link?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the cache key? If you set it to `$host$filename` then the key used for caching will contain the `$host` and `$filename` variable values.

Comment: what does it mean - "the key used for caching" ? would u please explain in two words...or point me to comprehensive explanation? thanks :)

Comment: oh, sorry...no link
got it from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584147/nginx-proxy-cache-key